# Logging the name of recipes using ingredients

Tags: javascript, json, performance

Given two objects with some food data, log the name of the recipe and ingredients names separated by conjunction "and". Please run the code I have attached to see the expected output.

condition - match RECIPES.rules.id with INGREDIENT.id and use INGREDIENT.name in the final output.

I was wondering if my solution can be improved? The fact that I am looping array inside an existing array loop makes me think this solution is not good.

```js
const INGREDIENTS = [
  {
    id: 'chocolate',
    name: 'Chocolate Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'milk_chocolate']
  },
  {
    id: 'm_and_ms',
    name: 'M&Ms',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['milk_chocolate']
  },
  {
    id: 'lemon',
    name: 'Lemon Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'lemon']
  },
  {
    id: 'peanuts',
    name: 'Peanuts',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['peanuts']
  },
  {
    id: 'vanilla',
    name: 'Vanilla Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'vanilla_extract']
  },
  {
    id: 'strawberry',
    name: 'Strawberry Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'strawberries']
  },
  {
    id: 'caramel',
    name: 'Caramel Sauce',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['caramel']
  },
  {
    id: 'raspberry',
    name: 'Raspberry Sauce',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['raspberries']
  }
];

// DOCSTRING
const RECIPES = [
  {
    id: 'the_basic',
    name: 'The Basic',
    rules: ['chocolate', 'vanilla']
  },
  {
    id: 'chocolate_lovers',
    name: 'Chocolate Lovers',
    rules: ['chocolate', 'm_and_ms', 'caramel']
  },
  {
    id: 'tooty_fruity',
    name: 'Tooty Fruity',
    rules: ['strawberry', 'raspberry', 'm_and_ms']
  }
];

const printRecipe = () => {
  RECIPES.forEach(recipe => {
    let recipeName = recipe.name;

    let listOfItems = recipe.rules.reduce((acc, currentIngredient, index) => {
      let result;
      let items = INGREDIENTS.find(ingrd => {
        return ingrd.id === currentIngredient;
      });
      if (acc.length === 0) {
        result = items.name;
      } else {
        result = `${acc} and ${items.name}`;
      }
      return result;
    }, '');
    console.log(`${recipeName} - ${listOfItems}`);
  });
};

printRecipe();
```

Comment: Looks good. To optimize it you would need a different datastructure, however this sounds like premature optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest two improvements:

- Use a Map to have a faster lookup in your ingredients. `find` needs to iterate through an array every time, while if you create a Map for it, you can get each result in constant time
- Use the `map` array method (unrelated to the above mentioned `Map` object) in combination with `join` instead of `reduce`.

Here is how that would look:

```js
const INGREDIENTS = [{id: 'chocolate',name: 'Chocolate Ice Cream',type: 'ice_cream',contains: ['cream', 'milk_chocolate']},{id: 'm_and_ms',name: 'M&Ms',type: 'topping',contains: ['milk_chocolate']},{id: 'lemon',name: 'Lemon Ice Cream',type: 'ice_cream',contains: ['cream', 'lemon']},{id: 'peanuts',name: 'Peanuts',type: 'topping',contains: ['peanuts']},{id: 'vanilla',name: 'Vanilla Ice Cream',type: 'ice_cream',contains: ['cream', 'vanilla_extract']},{id: 'strawberry',name: 'Strawberry Ice Cream',type: 'ice_cream',contains: ['cream', 'strawberries']},{id: 'caramel',name: 'Caramel Sauce',type: 'topping',contains: ['caramel']},{id: 'raspberry',name: 'Raspberry Sauce',type: 'topping',contains: ['raspberries']}];
const RECIPES = [{id: 'the_basic',name: 'The Basic',rules: ['chocolate', 'vanilla']},{id: 'chocolate_lovers',name: 'Chocolate Lovers',rules: ['chocolate', 'm_and_ms', 'caramel']},{id: 'tooty_fruity',name: 'Tooty Fruity',rules: ['strawberry', 'raspberry', 'm_and_ms']}];

const keyedIngredients = new Map(INGREDIENTS.map(o => [o.id, o.name]));
const printRecipe = () => {
  RECIPES.forEach(recipe => {
    let listOfItems = recipe.rules.map(
        ingredient => keyedIngredients.get(ingredient)
    ).join(" and ");
    console.log(`${recipe.name} - ${listOfItems}`);
  });
};

printRecipe();
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the `INGREDIENTS` into a Map (or object), that way you can access ingredients directly, rather than using `find`. Also, have the reducer return an *array* that is then turned into a string, rather than checking, formatting, and re-returning the string each time:

```js
const INGREDIENTS = [
  {
    id: 'chocolate',
    name: 'Chocolate Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'milk_chocolate']
  },
  {
    id: 'm_and_ms',
    name: 'M&Ms',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['milk_chocolate']
  },
  {
    id: 'lemon',
    name: 'Lemon Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'lemon']
  },
  {
    id: 'peanuts',
    name: 'Peanuts',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['peanuts']
  },
  {
    id: 'vanilla',
    name: 'Vanilla Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'vanilla_extract']
  },
  {
    id: 'strawberry',
    name: 'Strawberry Ice Cream',
    type: 'ice_cream',
    contains: ['cream', 'strawberries']
  },
  {
    id: 'caramel',
    name: 'Caramel Sauce',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['caramel']
  },
  {
    id: 'raspberry',
    name: 'Raspberry Sauce',
    type: 'topping',
    contains: ['raspberries']
  }
];


// DOCSTRING
const RECIPES = [
  {
    id: 'the_basic',
    name: 'The Basic',
    rules: ['chocolate', 'vanilla']
  },
  {
    id: 'chocolate_lovers',
    name: 'Chocolate Lovers',
    rules: ['chocolate', 'm_and_ms', 'caramel']
  },
  {
    id: 'tooty_fruity',
    name: 'Tooty Fruity',
    rules: ['strawberry', 'raspberry', 'm_and_ms']
  }
];

const ingredientsMap = new Map(INGREDIENTS.map(ingredient => [ingredient.id, ingredient]))

const printRecipe = () => {
  RECIPES.forEach(({ name, rules }) => {
    const listOfItems = rules.reduce((acc, currentIngredient, index) => {
      const name = ingredientsMap.get(currentIngredient).name;
      acc.push(name);
      return acc;
    }, []);
    console.log(`${name} - ${listOfItems.join(' AND ')}`);
  });
};

printRecipe();
```